# htaccess redirect url with dynamic values to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have some issues with Google indexing certain unwanted URLs on my site such as http://www.example.com/%22tel:333-444-1234, where the number part is dynamic. These pages do not exist, and I am hoping to remove these links from Google's index by using the rel="nofollow" tag. But meanwhile I would like to redirect all URLs containing the string "%22tel:" to a page on my site such as http://www.example.com/page1.html.

I am using Apache. How do I do this?

I tried these codes, it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\%22tel:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/page1.html/

RewriteRule ^(.*)\%22tel:(.*)$ http://www.example.com/page1.html [L,R=301]
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do these URLs come about in the first place, are you generating them? Would returning a 404 not be the more suitable way to remove the URLs from the search index?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yes, I generate the URLs. But the idea was to allow phone users to dial the number by clicking on the link. I am actually trying to remove them from the Google Search Console error list where I need to 'Fix' them.

Comment: Just sending a 404 would fix the problem relatively quickly... or having them in a subdirectory: `/tel/....`  and excluding it from search engines in the robots.txt.

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks! starkeen's answer solved the redirect issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /%22tel [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page-1.html [L,R]
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you :)